# Error while loading english module using spaCy

Tags: python, module, pycharm, package, spacy

I am writing code with spaCy and while loading 'en' English in, I receive an error.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

This is what I imported. I have installed nlp, spaCy and en_core_web_sm using pip.
I am using PyCharm IDE for this.
This is the error I get:

```
C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe "C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/MYP 5/ICT/ict_project/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aayus/Desktop/MYP 5/ICT/ict_project/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sumarization
  File "C:\Users\aayus\Desktop\MYP 5\ICT\ict_project\sumarization.py", line 3, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en')
  File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\Users\aayus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 175, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Load the small English model using its full name:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

If the model is not downloaded, run in the PyCharm terminal:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have already downloaded en_core_web_sm and when I run the full name for the English model, I am getting the same error: